# scope in directive does'nt work

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to add input element to my Google Map.
I wrote the following code:

```
app.directive('GooglePlaceAutoComplete', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'AEC',
    replace: true,
      scope: {     
        myMap:'='
        },
    template: '<input id="google_places" name="google_places" type="text" class="input-block-level"></input>',
    link: function($scope, elm , attr){

          var input = document.getElementById('google_places');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', $scope.myMap);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
          alert('changed');
        });
    }

  };
});
```

When I inspect the element I see that $scope.myMap == Undefined
And therefore get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'gm_bindings_' of undefined
    at kf (https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/3/main.js:25:19)
    at El.T.(anonymous function).bindTo (https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/3/main.js:25:204)
    at link (file:///Users/ortal/Desktop/Js%20Excersize%202/googlemapjs.js:28:22)
    at file:///Users/ortal/Desktop/Js%20Excersize%202/angular.min.js:72:222
    at $ (file:///Users/ortal/Desktop/Js%20Excersize%202/angular.min.js:72:278)
    at N (file:///Users/ortal/Desktop/Js%20Excersize%202/angular.min.js:61:294)
    at g (file:///Users/ortal/Desktop/Js%20Excersize%202/angular.min.js:54:244)
    at N (file:///Users/ortal/Desktop/Js%20Excersize%202/angular.min.js:61:239)
    at g (file:///Users/ortal/Desktop/Js%20Excersize%202/angular.min.js:54:244)
    at file:///Users/ortal/Desktop/Js%20Excersize%202/angular.min.js:53:282

When I remove the following:

```
scope: {     
            myMap:'='
            },


<div ng-app="app.ui-map" ng-controller="Controller">
    <section id="map">
        <div id="map_canvas" ui-map="myMap" 
            style="height:300px;width:400px;border:2px solid #777777;margin:3px; border:1px solid" 
            ui-options="mapOptions" 
            ui-event="{'map-idle' : 'onMapIdle()'}"
            >
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="marker in myMarkers" ui-map-marker="myMarkers[$index]"
                        ui-event="{'map-click': 'markerClicked(marker)'}"></div>
</section>
  <div GooglePlaceAutoComplete></div>
```

I get no error but the nothing happend when the address is changed

Comment: also add the html where you use the directive, so we can see what you're passing in as 'myMap'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
scope: true,
```

To your directive. Like this:

```
app.directive('GooglePlaceAutoComplete', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'AEC',
    replace: true,
    scope: true, <-------- HERE
      scope: {     
        myMap:'='
        },
        ...
        ...
```